# audio play & pause in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, audio

I'm trying to make a music app, I can start the audio fine, but when it comes to pausing it's not working this is the code :

```
const handlePlay = (id) => {
    console.log(id);
    audio && audio.pause();
    fetch(`https://spotify23.p.rapidapi.com/tracks/?ids=${id}`, options)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.tracks);
        return response.tracks[0].preview_url;
      })
      .then((response) => {
        setAudio(new Audio(response));
        audio.play();
      })
      .catch((err) => console.error(err));
  };
```

so I'm calling an API and getting the audio link here to play the audio :

```
setAudio(new Audio(response));
audio.play();
```

and at the top of the function I have this to check if audio is not null and if it is not so pause, like so:

```
audio && audio.pause();
```

but it's not working it's stacking the audio together, and even if I press on another audio it played the first one pressed

this is the react code that triggers handle play for each audio available :

```
{tracks &&
            tracks.map((track) => (
              <div
                className="w-full h-1/12 p-4 hover:bg-gray-300 hover:bg-opacity-20 hover:text-emerald-500 cursor-pointer  transition duration-150 "
                key={track.data.id}
                onClick={() => handlePlay(track.data.id)}
              >
                <div className="flex items-center ">
                  <svg
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                    fill="currentColor"
                    className="w-6 h-6 mr-2"
                  >
                    <path
                      fillRule="evenodd"
                      d="M4.5 5.653c0-1.426 1.529-2.33 2.779-1.643l11.54 6.348c1.295.712 1.295 2.573 0 3.285L7.28 19.991c-1.25.687-2.779-.217-2.779-1.643V5.653z"
                      clipRule="evenodd"
                    />
                  </svg>

                  <h1 className="text-xl ">{track.data.name}</h1>
                </div>
                <div className="text-sm font-thin">
                  by{" "}
                  {track.data.artists.items.map((artist) => (
                    <span key={artist.uri} className="">
                      {artist.profile.name}
                    </span>
                  ))}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is likely here:

```
setAudio(new Audio(response));
audio.play();
```

The `setAudio` function is asynchronous, so it will not immediately update the value for the `audio` state variable. That means that when you immediately invoke `audio.play()`, it is going to play the previous audio value.

If you want the audio to play automatically once it is loaded, then you can remove the `audio.play()` invocation in the fetch callback, and then add a `useEffect` hook to take care of that:

```
useEffect(() => {
  audio && audio.play();
}, [audio]);
```

Comment: thanks alot it worked i was smushing y brain lol